# A user defined function created for finding the area of triangle using Heron's formula

Tags: python

the below code is not returning any value after taking 3 inputs....please help

````
a = int(input('Enter the length of first side:'))
b = int(input('Enter the length of second side b:'))
c = int(input('Enter the length of third side c:'))
s = int((a+b+c) / 2)
def triangleArea(a,b,c,s):
    res = math.sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))
    print (res) ```
````

Comment: You have to call the function `triangleArea`. Put `triangleArea(a, b, c, s)` at the end. Side note: after doing that, you'll see that you can't do `s(s - a)`, has to be `s * (s - a)`.

Comment: Thanks for help Mr.Mario